# Keyboard shortcut to display error in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I like to use my mouse as little as possible for health reasons. Almost all the common tasks in IntelliJ I can do via keyboard shortcuts, except for displaying the message of an error. How can I have a keyboard shortcut that will show the tooltip of the highlighted error?

For example, I have an error such as:

[image]

Then I hit [magic-keyboard-command] and I get:

[image]

In Eclipse this is possible by pressing F2. Is there an equivalent in IntelliJ?

Comment: It is called "Error Description". You can search for it in the Preferences > IDE Settings > Keymap

Comment: If you use **visual studio copy**, try ALT + t.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The standard `Error Description` shortcut for JetBrains tools is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> on Mac).

Comment: This requires serious finger gymnastics on a MacBook... `CMD + FN + F1`. It almost causes carpal tunnel syndrome.

Comment: Ok, so I went into Intellij > Preferences > IDE Settings > Keymap > Main Menu > View > Error Description and remapped to `CMD + ENTER`.

Comment: @AaronMahan from one IntelliJ user on Mac to another, you might enjoy life more if you turn off that function key.  System Preferences > Keyboard > Use F1, F2, etc...

Comment: @jordanpg Indeed. If only that were an application-specific setting! I just have to be willing to force myself to re-learn using the FN key for volume, brightness, etc. It's really the lesser of two evils.

Comment: Even with ctrl-F1 (twice, to get the full text of the error message), every time I move the g-d mouse to make a note of the information contained in the full text popup so I can act on it, the full text goes away.  What is it with GUIs these days, that critical information has to be made available only by magic?  I can't even freaking copy/paste it to somewhere it will stay put.  I have to get out pencil and paper.  Really.

Comment: Ctrl + 1 in KDE scheme. Works ok for me.

Comment: Is it possible to make this window appear by just hovering the mouse over the underlined code?

Comment: `CMD + Enter` makes so much more sense. Esp considering thats in proximity to erorr-fix shorcut `OPTION + Enter`, and that the default on `CMD + Enter` is most of the time useless split line action.

Answer (score 7):

I use F2 on the mac, it cycles round all the errors in a single file and displays the error information for each.

In addition, to find all project errors what I do is this:

1. cmd+2 - go to error list (this might be different for diff languages)
2. press enter key
3. make change to fix bug
4. back to step 1 (sometimes escape key will help also)

Comment: does it display error though? for me it cycles, but no error pop-up until I manually trigger it. I've been searching a way to enable that error pop-up on F2 cycle forever, but no luck. Did you do something extra?