# How do I bring up the hover menu for an error in Intellij without mousing over it?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, popup

With the hover menu I mean the nice little yellow (in my case) menu that shows the error in a couple of lines when you hover over a word or symbol that's marked with a red line. I know how to navigate to it (F2, shift+f2) but once I'm at it I can just use the keyboard to hit ctrl+enter and get the possible solutions, I actually don't know how to use it to bring up the error window up itself so I can see what it's about.

Comment: Dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346245/keyboard-shortcut-to-display-error-in-intellij

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has been answered here: [Keyboard shortcut to display error in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346245/keyboard-shortcut-to-display-error-in-intellij)

You can use Ctrl+F1.

Also, the shortcut to view solutions is Alt+Enter I believe, not Ctrl+Enter.

Answer (score 3):

On a mac keyboard use Cmd + F1 to bring up the hover menu for an error